# This is the code that's leading up to my class-based card game "Go Fish", but I cannot figure out how to do __str__ method for my Deck/Player class

Tags: python

'''
I am trying to figure out how to do the **str** method on my Deck and Player class. I can print an individual instance of my Card class, but that is it. Once I start trying to print my deck, I get an error code telling me that the list index is out of range. I know I am making a noob mistake somewhere and just don't realize it. If I can get these methods done, I can go ahead and code the game. I will put up all the code necessary to help if someone is up to it. Also need a **str** method for showing a player's hand too I guess. Here is the error code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\kille\OneDrive\Desktop\HW9\revised_classes.py", line 139, in 
print(deck)
File "c:\Users\kille\OneDrive\Desktop\HW9\revised_classes.py", line 67, in **str**
vis.append(str(card))
File "c:\Users\kille\OneDrive\Desktop\HW9\revised_classes.py", line 16, in **str**
return f"{Card.values[self.value]}{Card.suits[self.suit]}"
IndexError: list index out of range
'''

```
class Card:
    #This class represents a playing card.
    suits = ['\u2666', '\u2665', '\u2663', '\u2660']
    values = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
    '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        #Initialize attributes of card class.
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
    # This works, but if it can be done better I am up for suggestions
    def __str__(self):
        #Returns a card
        return f"{Card.values[self.value]}{Card.suits[self.suit]}"

    def __repr__(self):
        #Learning about this one
        return f"{Card.values[self.value]}{Card.suits[self.suit]}"
    
    def __eq__(self, card2):
        #equal operator, compares the values of the cards
        if self.value == card2.value:
            return self.value == card2.value
        else:
            return False
    

    def get_value(self):
        #This function returns the value of a card
        value = self.value
        return print(value)

    def get_suit(self):
        #This function returns the suit of a card
        return print(self.suit)

    def same_value(self, card):
        #This function checks to see if two cards have the same value.
        if self.value == card.value:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def same_suit(self, card):
        #This function checks to see if two cards have the same suit.
        if self.suit == card.suit:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Deck:
    #This class represents a deck of playing cards.
    def __init__(self):
        #Initialize attributes for the Deck class
        self.deck = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for value in range(13):
                self.deck.append(Card(value, suit))
        self.shuffle_deck()
    
    #This is where I need to print the deck, but haven't figured it out yet
    def __str__(self):
        #This function returns a string representation of the deck.
        vis = []
        for card in self.deck:
            vis.append(str(card))
        return vis                  
    def __len__(self):
        #This function returns the length of the deck
        return len(self.deck)

    def add_card(self, card):
        #This function adds a card to the deck
        self.deck.append(card)

    def shuffle_deck(self):
        #This function shuffles the deck of playing cards
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def draw_card(self):
        #This function allows you to draw a card from the deck
        drawn_card = self.deck.pop()
        print(drawn_card)
        return drawn_card

    def gt_rd_card(self):
        #This function gets a random card from the deck
        return random.choice(self.deck)

class Player(Deck):
    #This class represents a player in a game and inherits from the Deck class
    def __init__(self, name):
        #Initialize attributes of the Player(Deck) class
        self.name = name
        self.wins = 0
        self.pairs = []
        self.hand = []
        deck = Deck()
    #This is where I need to figure out how to print a player's hand
    def __str__(self):
        #This allows me to print
        return self.name + ': ' + ' '.join([str(card) for card in self.deck])

    def get_name(self):
        #This function returns the name of the player
        return self.name

    def get_wins(self):
        #This function allows me to get the wins
        return self.wins

    def draw_card(self):
        #This function allows a player to draw a card
        self.hand.append(deck.draw_card)
        return self.hand

    # I also need to set up deal_hand(which will be 7 cards) and figure out how to print that
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: What's your `Card.values`? It looks like a list, but I didn't find the assignment statement in your code; Method `__str__` should always returns a string, you just need use `repr(vis)` in `Deck.__str__` to return the string of list.

Comment: That can't be your code.  The `__init__` function for `Card` needs two parameters.  Your code wouldn't work as is.  My guess is you have swapped `value` and `suit`.

Comment: Is ```Card.values[...]``` even defined?

Comment: Must of not copied and pasted everything, now its in there

Comment: Try printing out the values of ```self.value``` and ```self.suit``` before ```return f"{Card.values[self.value]}{Card.suits[self.suit]}"```

Comment: @MechanicPig, can you show me on my code exactly what you mean because I tried using repr(vis) and got same result. I'm still new to coding so I haven't used any of the __ methods much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the assignment of `Card.values`: there is no `,` separation between `'9'` and `'10'`, resulting in the merging of the two strings into `'910'`, so the actual value list is shorter than you think.

In fact, it's easy to find this problem, you just need to traverse the `Deck.deck` and print the card, and you'll find 910♦ existence.

For method `Deck.__ str__`, a simpler implementation is to return `str(self.deck)` or `repr(self.deck)`

Comment: your right, I did leave out some commas. That doesn't fix my issue with printing the deck. I still get the same error message whether I use repr or str.

Comment: thank you so much. Now I just feel stupid. lol

Comment: @CameronBratten Are you sure you got the same error? After adding `,`, the index should not cross the boundary. Make sure your method `Deck.__str__` returns a string.

Comment: Pic, no we are good now, I noticed another mistake and fixed it and applied what you told me and we are in business. Thanks to you I got my deal hand function and show hand function working as well. Now I can program my game class to run "Go Fish". Thanks again.